# Como excluir apk publicado na GooglePlay

Tags: android, google-play, admob

Olá, desenvolvi um jogo em GameMaker e publiquei na Google Play na categoria "Para toda a família" mas esse fato fez com que a propaganda da AdMob parasse de aparecer no jogo. Não havia explicação sobre esse fato na qualificação para essa categoria de aplicativo.

Agora não consigo mais alterar o cadastro do meu aplicativo na GooglePlay pois já foi publicado. Criei uma nova versão mas somente me permitiu enviar um novo apk.

Existe a possibilidade de excluir um aplicativo da loja para reinserí-lo ou a possibilidade de alterar o cadastro do aplicativo na loja ? Não consegui executar nenhuma dessas duas ações.

Encontrei este único artigo falando sobre o assunto mas não tem como inserir no GameMaker : https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6223431?hl=en

Obrigado.

Comment: A resposta encontra-se neste post do SOeng:<br />
[How to remove application from app listings on android developer console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074972/how-remove-application-from-app-listings-on-android-developer-console)

Comment: Obrigado, abraços

Answer (score 12):

Acesse o Play Console e selecione o app.

1. Selecione Presença na loja
2. Preços e distribuição.
3. Na seção "Disponibilidade do app", selecione Desfazer publicação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Prints são bem-vindos

Comment: Eu só queria tirar de produção e deixar a BETA e ALFA no ar, será que tem como?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Play Console Atual]

Atualmente isto é feito em:

1. Configurações
2. Definições Avançadas
3. Passar para "Não Publicada"